# set reorderableColumn property to specific column of primeng datatable angular 2

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using [primeng datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/colreorder)

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" reorderableColumns="true">
  <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
  <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
  <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
  <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

In above code, I don't want to allow reordering to column "color".(Want to set **reorderableColumns="false" to "color" column**).

Anyone having any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no support of selected column ordering in primeng datatable. A 
 callback `onColReorder()` is provided by primeng that only invoke after the completion of ordering.

If you want to achieve this kind of functionality then you can try the following patch code.

```
<div style="width:75%;float:left">
    <p-dataTable [value]="cars" reorderableColumns="true">
        <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
        <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
        <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
<div style="width:25%;float:left">
    <p-dataTable [value]="cars">
        <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

Comment: New p-table aka TurboTable has this easy by adding pReorderableColumn to the columns that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **pReorderableColumnDisabled** attribute to what ever column you dont want to reorder.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" reorderableColumns="true">
     <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
     <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
     <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
     <p-column field="color" header="Color" [pReorderableColumnDisabled]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Happy Coding :)